# C - Write in plain text file struct variables in newline

Tags: c, file, struct, newline

I'm trying to write the variables of a struct data type in a file (config.dat) separated by newline, i.e.:

```
9001
00
128930
2
```

But I can only write them without spaces:

```
9001001289302
```

This is the code:

```
int main()
{
  typedef struct
  {
    char cp[4];
    char id[2];
    char correlative[6];
    char digit[1];
  } log;

  FILE *fl;
  log new_log;

  fl = fopen("config.dat", "w");

  printf ("\nCP: ");
  gets (new_log.cp);
  printf ("ID: ");
  gets (new_log.id);
  printf ("Correlative: ");
  gets (new_log.correlative);
  printf ("Digit");
  gets (new_log.digit);

  fwrite(&new_log, sizeof(log), 1, fl);

  fclose(fl);

  return 0;
}
```

What can I do? Thank you!

Comment: you never open `fl` file. fix that please.

Comment: Fixed. I deleted that line by mistake.

Comment: The way you are writing your file is wrong. It is impossible that data written in this way gets a new line...

Comment: Don't ever use `gets()`. Never, ever use `gets()`. It's so lethal it has (finally) been removed from Standard C. The first Internet worm exploited `gets()` (Google search 'morris internet worm'). Use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) from Standard C or
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) from POSIX, but be aware these include the newline in the result where `gets()` does not. On some systems, you may be able to use `gets_s()` (Microsoft systems; also C11 Annex K, but often not available.)

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I've changed `gets` by `scanf`, in this case was the first solution I've found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you actually need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    typedef struct
    {
        char cp[1 + 1 + 4];
        char id[1 + 1 + 2];
        char correlative[1 + 1 + 6];
        char digit[1 + 1 + 1];
    } log;
    /* I add `1' for the terminating null byte '\0', and another `1' for the `\n` new line */

    FILE *fl;
    log   new_log;

    fl = fopen("config.dat", "w");
    if (fl == NULL)
        return 1;

    printf ("\nCP: ");
    fgets (new_log.cp, sizeof(new_log.cp), stdin);
    fprintf (fl, "%s", new_log.cp);

    printf ("ID: ");
    fgets (new_log.id, sizeof(new_log.id), stdin);
    fprintf (fl, "%s", new_log.id);

    printf ("Correlative: ");
    fgets (new_log.correlative, sizeof(new_log.correlative), stdin);
    fprintf (fl, "%s", new_log.correlative);

    printf ("Digit: ");
    fgets (new_log.digit, sizeof(new_log.digit), stdin);
    fprintf (fl, "%s", new_log.digit);


    fclose(fl);

    return 0;
}
```

notice that i've used `fgets` to aviod buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are writing your data is wrong, if you use `fwrite()`, you write the full block of data to the file without inserting any newlines. If you want to insert newlines, then you should rather use something like `fprintf()` or insert newlines manually between `fwrite()`

Answer (score 0):

if your data are

```
9001
00
128930
2
```

the struct typedef should be

```
typedef struct
  {
    char cp[5];
    char id[3];
    char correlative[7];
    char digit[2];
  } log;
```

For example 9001 will be stored in cp member as 9001\0 and the zero char will overflow on id member, and so on , that's why you get 9001001289302...

Comment: perhaps getting the question literally you are right , but given that the guy is learning c , \n is not relevant in this context, i mean \n is neither entered by gets nor is should be stored in the structure

Comment: I agree null termintaion byte is a very common problem for beginers.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes. Luca is right, but that only works if I use `fprintf` instead `fwrite`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  typedef struct 
  {
    char cp[5];
    char id[3];
    char correlative[7];
    char digit[2];
  } log;

  FILE *fl;
  log new_log;

  if (!(fl = fopen("config.dat", "w")))
  { 
    printf ("An error occurred while opening file.\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf ("\nIntroducir codigo postal (5 digitos): ");
    scanf ("%s", new_log.cp);
    printf ("Introducir identificador de la administracion (2 digitos): ");
    scanf ("%s", new_log.id);
    printf ("Introducir numero correlativo (7 digitos): ");
    scanf ("%s", new_log.correlative);
    printf ("Introducir precio de la apuesta: ");
    scanf ("%s", new_log.digit);

    fprintf(fl, "%s %s %s %s", new_log.cp, new_log.id, new_log.correlative, new_log.digit);
  }

  fclose(fl);

  return 0;
}
```